# "Sequence contains more than one element" while converting db data to List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
//searchText contains tags in one string. E.g. "programming javascript angular"
string[] separators = { " " };
//Splitting string to array
List<string> tags = searchText.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

//getting notes which all tags equals tags given by user            
var allNotes = db.Notes.Where(dbnote => tags.All(givenTag => dbnote.NoteTags.Any(dbNoteTag => dbNoteTag.Tag.Name == givenTag))).Include(x => x.NoteTags).ThenInclude(x => x.Tag);
var dataToList = allNotes.ToList();
```

Problem appears in the last line.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element

Note:

```
public class Note
    {
        public Note()
        {
            NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
        [...]
    }
```

NoteTag

```
public class NoteTag
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public Note Note { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Tag

```
public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EF code first uses conventions during the mapping. One of the convention is that it treats properties named Id or TypenameId as primary keys (if you don't use the Key attribute or custom mapping) and because it does the property name comparison case insensitively it throws the exception.

Further more, your NoteTag table has NoteId(FK) and TagId(FK) but your Note has ID(PK) and Tag has ID(PK)
Note:

```
public class Note
    {
        public Note()
        {
            NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>();
        }
        //primary key
        public int NoteId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
        [...]
    }
```

NoteTag

```
public class NoteTag
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public Note Note { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Tag

```
public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>();
    }
    // primary key
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so, do you think that changing names of keys is all I need to do? Is it safe to do this with some currently existing data?

Comment: No, The model has changed now so you ll have to drop your database.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the names, effect the same

Comment: @Ludwik11 sorry that didn't work. I can suggest one more thing  var allNotes = db.Notes.Include(x => x.NoteTags).ThenInclude(x => x.Tag).Where(dbnote => tags.All(givenTag => dbnote.NoteTags.Any(dbNoteTag => dbNoteTag.Tag.Name == givenTag)));